# How to print product labels from PHP

Tags: php, printing, label

I am working on a shopping cart. The client requirement says once an item is entered, they need a popup to print the "Product label" with "product id" etc . I have never worked with printers php stuff. My question is

1. what is the best way to go about this?
2. Shall i just create a popop with print button  ? ie will the printer print the dimensions of the popup.?
3. According to the requirement , I think we need to print 1 label at a time. Is there printer which does that. My doubt because Most say 10-100 labels per sheet. According to the requirement , I can print only one at a time?

Please provide me ideas on how i can get this done.

Comment: 1) Print stylesheets or output to PDF, 2) sure or open in native pdf viewer for printing. 3) Look at Zebra Printers for outputing labels.

Comment: I suggest to look at the actualreports.com. They provide a document creation platform for software providers and developers. You can create different documents (including labels in any format) in their browser based editor and then get the pdf/html output via API. Basically they cover the functionality commented by Organgepill in the first point.

Comment: Thanks  @Orangepill I followed your advice and now have it working. Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Orangepill I followed your advice and now have it working. Sorry for the late reply

Since @Orangepill provided a comment , i am putting the answer to mark the question as solved.

What i did in short was converted the code to pdf. set page size of pdf to label size and it printed correctly on a label printer.